# Split a column in spark scala into array type column and string type column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So my data looks like this

```
"my_data,another_data,"[0,1,3,2,4]","[0,1,2,3,4]""
```

What I want is

```
["my_data","another_data","[0,1,3,2,4]","[0,1,2,3,4]"]
```

What I have tried so far is:-

```
  df.withColumn("valueSplit",split(col("value"),",\"|\","))
```

this gives me

```
["my_data,another_data","[0,1,2,3,2,4]"","[0,1,2,3,4]"]
```

Thanks is advance!

Comment: How did you get that string, it's sort of different

Comment: Well, cant complain about the data that we are getting.System generated.

Comment: Looks odd to me. Ok

Comment: expecting 4 or 12 values?

Comment: suspct 4, but is this representative of all records?

Comment: I am looking for a universal solution, I am getting around 15 files, most of them have this problem, each one has a different schema.

Comment: then you need to state that in the question. it is not that simple.